# BASH: Adding numbers to an element of array

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I'm learning shall scripting, and I wonder if there's any way to add numbers to an element of an array so that the number would be added to the element instead of appending it.

```
num=1
declare -A array
array[0]+=$num
array[0]+=$num
echo ${array[0]}
```

obviously, the result would be '11' instead of 2. I know this question might exists in the community, but I couldn't find it maybe because I don't know how to name the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use arithmetic context `((..))`:

```sh
num=1
declare -A array
((array[0]+=$num))
((array[0]+=$num))
echo ${array[0]}

2
```

Answer (score 2):

Giving the array the [integer attribute](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-declare) enables "bare" arithmetic:

```sh
num=1
declare -Ai array
array[0]+=$num         
array[0]+=num        # also works without expanding the variable
                     # because this is arithmetic evaluation
declare -p array
```

outputs

```
declare -Ai array=([0]="2" )
```

`-A` defines an *associative* array. `-i` also works with `-a` numerically-indexed arrays.